# linux issue when searching for a specific column

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file( ddat.txt ) with 1000 records and want to output specific columns

Eg:

```
    prodrhcnfs31:/export/home_edl/zsahab nfs   3219128320 1960459264 1248838656      62% /home/zsahab
    prodrhcnfs31:/export/home_edl/zwang nfs   3219128320 1960459264 1248838656      62% /home/zwang
    prodrhcnfs31:/export/home_edl/zyuan1 nfs   3219128320 1960459264 1248838656      62% /home/zyuan1
```

I need to print the following output:

```
    prodrhcnfs31:/export/home_edl/zsahab     nfs   /home/zsahab
```

I tried `sed 's/^.*prodrhcnfs31=//' ddat.txt` it doesnt print the above

Comment: `awk '{print $1,$2,$7}' ddat.txt`?

Comment: yeah  prefixed with white spaces

Comment: awk '{print $1,$2,$7}' ddat.txt  thanks for the help